# Paypal Payment Pro Hosted not working with One Step Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-pro

During checkout process when order is placed with Paypal Payment Pro Hosted, without asking any credential it successfully placed the order. The problem with the one step checkout extension. With magento default checkout,payment hosted is working fine.

For Debug,I gone through these steps and found every thing is already present.

1. The themename/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml must
       include the following call, after the list of shopping cart items:

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('items_after'); ?>
   ```
2. The corresponding layout file themename/layout/onestepcheckout.xml must
   include the items_after block referenced above. So, the following
   should appear within the checkout_onepage_review section of
   onestepcheckout.xml:

   ```
   <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label"><label>Items After</label></block>
   ```
3. Once these two steps are done, the
   frontend/base/default/template/paypal/hss/js.phtml file will be
   automatically rendered in the review stage of the onestep checkout.

But still facing the problem.

Thanks

Comment: if this is a commercial extension for checkout , please contact extension vendor support.

Comment: yes, I have contacted extension support, got this reply from them  "Payments Pro Hosted Solution (Includes Express Checkout) are not supported in our extension. We will work to get this fixed and will provide you with changed files as soon as possible"