# Magento: Unable to set Limit to Custom Collection of Admin Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, product-grid

I have created a custom module to show the data in admin grid

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('test_testing/order_collection');
    $collection->setProductFilter($this->_product->getId())->setParentItemIdFilter();
    $coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $collection->getSelect()
               ->joinLeft(array('billing_address' => $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_address')),
                    '`sales_order`.`billing_address_id` = `billing_address`.`entity_id`',
                    array('customer_firstname'  =>  'billing_address.firstname', 
                        'customer_lastname'     =>  'billing_address.lastname',
                        'customer_email'        =>  'billing_address.email',
                    ));

    $collection->getSelect()->limit(2);      
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Instead of 2 produts, It return's 4 products in admin grid.

I tried to print the query `echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();`  and if i run the sql query it returns the correct record (i.e. 2)

I tried with `->setPage(1, 1);` but still unable to resolve this issue.

It's Simple thing but still don't know what is missing.
Please help.

Comment: Just a try... Have you tried $collection->setPageSize(2) instead of $collection->getSelect()->limit(2) ?

Comment: yes, it return all 4 records

Comment: its basic thing, i dun know why sometime simple thing give problem in magento :(

Comment: Admin grid collections are normally affected by its toolbar / pager... so it's not as basic as it seems... Maybe you can play with _preparePage() method in your class, and try to force that parameters, although I think that would break user input in toolbar / pager. Take a look at Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid class

Comment: yes, i tried with _preparePage() method  protected function _preparePage()
 {
  $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(1);
  $this->getCollection()->setCurPage(1);
 }

Comment: It shows total 4 records 1 record per page

Comment: Ok, let me search something I did in a project some time ago... and I'll post as answer, although I am not sure it would apply in this case

Comment: So, let's see if it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think problem here is the logic having place when calling

```
return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

Which sets all the paging thing & load the collection. Just a try, not tested in this scenario

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('test_testing/order_collection');
    $collection->setProductFilter($this->_product->getId())->setParentItemIdFilter();
    $coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $collection->getSelect()
               ->joinLeft(array('billing_address' => $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_address')),
                    '`sales_order`.`billing_address_id` = `billing_address`.`entity_id`',
                    array('customer_firstname'  =>  'billing_address.firstname', 
                        'customer_lastname'     =>  'billing_address.lastname',
                        'customer_email'        =>  'billing_address.email',
                    ));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $this->getCollection()->clear()->setPageSize(2)->load();
    return $this;
}
```

If this works, I suppose it would break any input change by the user in Admin grid toolbar / pagination (but I understand it's precisely what you want to get)

Comment: still returning 4 products, 2 products in each page

Comment: WHERE (`main_table`.product_id = '16') AND (ISNULL(parent_item_id) OR parent_item_id = '') ORDER BY qty_ordered DESC LIMIT 2

sql query is exactly correct, but how its overiding the sql query, very strange

Comment: after few modification now its showing 2 products and only 1 page is displaying in pagination,which is correct,the only one problem is it show "Total 4 records found " :P

Comment: Hi Raul, can you help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260088/magento2-how-to-use-custom-collection-data-in-ui-component-grid